# How can I rewrite the HTML page to have the exact same fields?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make a new look for my website, but it looks like it doesn't want to login and I don't understand why.. Here's the original page:

```
<body class="jumbotron vertical-center" onload="redirect();">
    <div class="container login-container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 login-form mx-auto">
                <h3>Login</h3>
                <h6>Don't have an account?<a href="page/registration.php" class=""> Register</a></h6>
                <form>
                    <div class="error-message" id="errorMessage"></div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input id="enterID" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your User ID *" value="" required/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Password *" value="" required/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input class="btn btn-block btn-primary" value="Login" onclick="login();" readonly />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <a href="page/forget-password.php" class="ForgetPwd">Trouble logging in?</a>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And here's the edited page:

```
<!-- To keep it in the center of page-->
<img class="wave" src="img/wave.png">
    <div class="container_main">
        <div class="img">
            <img src="img/bg.svg">
        </div>
        <div class="login-content">
            <form>
                
                <img src="img/avatar.svg">
                <h2 class="title">Quiz Website</h2>
                <div class="input-div one">
                   <div class="i">
                        <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                   </div>
                   <div class="div">
                        <input type="text" class="input" id="enterID" placeholder="Username">
                   </div>
                </div>
                <div class="input-div pass">
                   <div class="i"> 
                        <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
                   </div>
                   <div class="div form-group">
                        <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" value="" required/>
                   </div>

                </div>
                <a href="page/registration.php">Don't have an account?</a>
                <div class="form-group">
                        <a href="page/forget-password.php" class="ForgetPwd">Trouble logging in?</a>
                    </div>
                <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Login" onclick="login();" readonly >
                <div class="error-message" id="errorMessage"></div>
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong? I don't want to use the body class jumbotron vertical-center cause it's making my website to look very awful.. I always get ,,XHR loading failed" and I don't understand why..

My checklogin.js file:

```
function login() {
    var enterID = document.getElementById("enterID").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    if ((password != "") && (enterID != "")) {
        var info = "?enterID=" + enterID + "&password=" + password;
        $.ajax
            ({
                type: "GET",
                url: "php/login.php" + info,
                success: function (respond) {
                    if (respond == "admin") {
                        window.location.href = "page/admin-system-management.php";
                    } else if (respond == "student") {
                        window.location.href = "page/student-dashboard.php";
                    } else if (respond == "teacher") {
                        window.location.href = "page/teacher-dashboard.php";
                    } else {
                        document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerText = respond;
                    }


                }
            });
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerText = "Please fill in all the fields.";
    }
}

function redirect() {
    $.ajax
        ({
            type: "GET",
            url: "php/redirect.php",
            success: function (respond) {

                if (respond != "not logged.") {
                    if (respond == "admin") {
                        window.location.href = "page/admin-system-management.php";
                    } else if (respond == "student") {
                        window.location.href = "page/student-dashboard.php";
                    } else if (respond == "teacher") {
                        window.location.href = "page/teacher-dashboard.php";
                    }
                }
            }
        });
}
```

And my login.php file:

```
<?php
        include "mysql-connect.php";
        
        //get Info from login.html
        $ID = $_GET['enterID'];
        $PW = $_GET['password'];

        $stmt = $connect->prepare("SELECT PW, userType, nickName FROM users WHERE ID = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s",$ID);
        $valid = $stmt->execute();
        if (!$valid){
            die("Could not successfully run query.". $connect->connect_error);
        }
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        if ($result->num_rows==0){
            //display message of no such student/teacher/admin
            echo "Failed to find an account with the input ID.";
        } else {
            $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
            if (password_verify($PW, $row['PW'])) {
                $type = $row['userType'];
                $nick = $row['nickName'];
                //var_dump($row['PW']);
                //save data
                if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
                    session_start();
                }
                $_SESSION["type"]=$type;
                $_SESSION["userID"]=$ID;
                $_SESSION["nickName"]=$nick;
                //login success - Request.responseText to checklogin.js
                echo $type;

            } else {
                //display message of password error
                echo "The input password does not match the account password.";
            }
        }
        $connect->close();
?>
```

And here's the redirect.php:

```
<?php
    if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
        session_start();
    }
    if (isset($_SESSION["type"])){
        if ($_SESSION["type"] != $_SESSION["pageType"]){
            $alert_message = "You cannot access this page using your account!";
            $link = "../login.html";
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$alert_message'); window.setTimeout(function(){ if ('".$_SESSION["type"]."'=='admin'){ window.location.href = '../page/admin-system-management.php';} else if ('".$_SESSION["type"]."'=='student'){ window.location.href = '../page/student-dashboard.php';} else if ('".$_SESSION["type"]."'=='teacher'){ window.location.href = '../page/teacher-dashboard.php';}  }, 0);</script>";
        }
    } else {
        $alert_message = "Your login period has expired! Please login again!";
        $link = "../login.html";
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$alert_message'); window.setTimeout(function(){ window.location.href = '$link'; }, 0);</script>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: @KIKOSoftware it's not, if I'm using the initial page it is working very good, I think it's only a problem with the HTML code

Comment: ```onload="redirect();``` you forgot to add this in your new look..

Comment: I've added to the form tag, but it looks like it's not working... @MD.RAKIBHASAN

Comment: check if it is calling api in the network tab. if yes the check what is the response. if you are receiving the response then check what is the data of respond. If your respond is not what you are expecting it is backend that need to be modified it is not calling api at all then javascript have issue.

Comment: @souravsatyam at the query string parameters I'm receiving user and pass, but it looks like it doesn't want to redirect to that page...I can also see the functions the that i;m calling, but it's not redirecting..

Comment: @souravsatyam and I also need to wait for 2-3 seconds in order to login again, so I can't login instantaneously

Comment: check network tab or do `console.log(respond)` inside success function and let me know what response you are receiving

Comment: @souravsatyam <br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Undefined array key "pageType" in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\eo\php\redirect.php</b> on line <b>6</b><br />
<script type='text/javascript'>alert('You cannot access this page using your account!'); window.setTimeout(function(){ if ('admin'=='admin'){ window.location.href = '../page/admin-system-management.php';} else if ('admin'=='student'){ window.location.href = '../page/student-dashboard.php';} else if ('admin'=='teacher'){ window.location.href = '../page/teacher-dashboard.php';}  }, 0);</script>

Comment: so your `$_SESSION["pageType"]` has issue . no session with key pageType exists

Comment: @souravsatyam so there's nothing I can do?

Comment: @souravsatyam this means that the redirect function it's not loading, what can I do?